# can you give admin permission in Terminal while logged into an account with restricted access?

Tags: macos, terminal, admin

I'm using Terminal on a mac. My user account (for work) does not have admin access, and I'm getting access denied on a lot of commands.

~Sudo does not work since I don't have admin access.~

I do have an account on this computer that has admin access, but that I shouldn't be logged into all day long. Is there a way to give/get administrator access via using username and password in the terminal? Ideally I'd like to be able to be logged into my non-admin account, open terminal, and provide the admin username and password when attempting something that needs admin access/permission. (rather than logging out of one account to log into the other just for the admin-access-required command, and then logging back into the restricted account)

Answer (score 2):

In terminal you can “su [account]” to the privileged account; enter password and then try the command; if it still needs privileges then you can “sudo” in the privileged account.